# Docker - how to save current container as a tar file and transfer it to another computer?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I downloaded basic Ubuntu docker image and ran it as a container and setup several stuff in it.

Now want to save that as one big file and transfer over to another computer and load it in docker as image and run it as container.

What are the steps to achieve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `docker export continerid > file.tar` to save container and then `docker import tarfile newimage` And `docker run newimage` On the target system.